# How do I detach a local SVN working copy?

Tags: svn

I cannot just `rm -rf $(find . -name '.svn')`, because I've got some directories in my working copy which are unversioned (on svn:ignore) and at the same time working copies of other svn repositories.

`my-repo

|+ directory

||- .svn (to delete)

||- files...

|+ another_directory

||- .svn (to delete)

||- files...

|+ directory_ignored (svn:ignore)

||- .svn (different working copy)

||- more files ...`

So I'd like to just tell subversion to remove all .svn directories belonging to this working copy only.

Is this possible?

The directory structure is quite complex, so doing it manually would really suck.

Edit: The working solution finally is:

`for i in $(export IFS=$'\n'; grep -l 'https://complete-repo-path/' find . -name entries|grep .svn | sed 's/ /\ /' | sed 's/.svn/entries//'); do echo $i.svn; done`

Comment: Not sure whether it will work, but you could try a `svn export` and tell svn to also export unversioned files (I don't know how to do that from the command line, though, I'm a Tortoisian :)

Comment: @Vulcan, it doesn't seem to when exporting a working copy: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html too bad, it would have been the solution otherwise. It's possible to get a clean copy of the working directory but that doesn't preserve the ignored files.

Comment: You could get a list of all ignores, with `svn propget`, then do as you propose and delete the `.svn` directories recursively from directories not mentioned among the ignored.

Comment: @Pekka: This wouldn't have worked here because the directory is about 80 GB and the partition about 120 ;)

Comment: @calmh Right. But the svn:ignore output is quite hard to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a workaround but still...

This will give you the list of directories containing the URL of your svn repository:

```
grep -l 'https://yourhost/svn/your_working_copy' `find . -name entries|grep .svn` | sed 's/\.svn\/entries//' | xargs echo
```

If it seems correct to you, you may `rm -rf` them after that

Comment: Thank you! Nice one. This worked. I had to slightly modify the expression to make it handle filenames with spaces too by setting the file separator character: for i in $(export IFS=$'\n'; grep -l 'https://yourhost/svn/your_working_copy' $(find . -name entries|grep .svn) | sed 's/\.svn\/entries//'); do echo '##' $i '##'; done  (converted `` to $() as is formatting syntax in the comments)

Comment: I noticed that this didn't handle whitespaces correctly; Corrected expression added in the question.